# SSIS package not hitting break point

Tags: sql-server, ssis, breakpoints

I have created an SSIS package in SQL Server. In Data Flow I have added a Script Task in which there is a break point. When I started debugging the package, it hit the break point and everything went fine.
Then I made some changes in code in Script Task and now break point won't hit. I have tried everything but no luck. I have even did the following as per Microsoft but same issue.

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2010/03/17/why-the-breakpoints-that-i-set-in-my-script-task-not-script-component-in-the-data-flow-never-hits.aspx

In the package it self it shows that Red circle on Script Task which means there is a break point but it never hits. When I debug the package and it reaches the Script Task, then looks like it is trying to open the editor and hit the break point but then it automatically closes and continues with the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes I restarted the SSIS service.

Comment: Yes I have restarted SSDT twice but no luck. Now I have restarted the machine so let's see what happens.

Comment: Same problem after restarting machine.

Comment: Ok I reverted the changes which were described by article above and now it works.

Comment: I made some changes and now breakpoint won't hit. This tool is a BIG JOKE!

Comment: A Script Task exists on the Control Flow. A Script Component exists inside a Data Flow. The names are similar but the ability to use a break point with a Script Component has only been available since the 2012 release of SSIS. Which scripting object are you using? Which version of of SSIS are you using (2005/2008/2008r2/2012/2014)? Post your code.

Comment: @FrankMartin Your primary intetion is to test out SSDT and you are using 2012? You shouldn't face these issues in 2008 and I believe it's mostly after that...likely 2010, 2012...

Comment: Sorry yes it's a script task inside control flow and not data flow. I am using SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 (all 64 bit)

Comment: Did you switch the project to 32bit?

Comment: some functions disable the debugger... comment out your code until you find the line responsible. Look here for two examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677400/vs-2015-ssis-script-tasks-cannot-be-debugged