# SSIS VSTA: Why does Script Component debugger not work when using TryGetValue on a dictionary?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, ssis

The VSTA debugger has... well... bugs in it. For example, string interpolation is not supported and will prevent the debugger from launching. That is [mitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677400/vs-2015-ssis-script-tasks-cannot-be-debugged) by using `String.Format();`. However, I have found another bug that I cannot seem to get around and that is using `TryGetValue()` on a dictionary. The below code prevents the debugger from launching:

```
foreach (string strMemberDn in varGroupMemberDns)
{   
    if (dctObjectGuidDn.TryGetValue(strMemberDn, out Guid gidMemberGuid))
    {
        lstGroupMemberGuid.Add(gidMemberGuid);
    }
}
```

Currently, I have to use the following if I want to debug the script, or I have to comment out the above section.

```
foreach (string strMemberDn in varGroupMemberDns)
{   
    lstGroupMemberGuid.Add(dctObjectGuidDn[strMemberDn]);
}
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: And also when you use Datetime.tryparse