# Executing SQL with parameters in SSIS

Tags: ssis

How do I execute the SQL script below a SSIS project? I've tried setting up parameters & variables; however.... nothing I do seems to pass the parameters via SSIS

```
declare @businessunit varchar(255) = 'Test'
declare @advisor varchar(255) = 'Smith'
declare @iuid int = 
(
        select       U.[iuid]
        from         U
        inner join   [dbo].A on u.[ipartyid] = A.[iuserid]
        inner join   [dbo].B on A.[ibusinessunitid] = B.[ipartyid]
        inner join   [dbo].C on u.[ipartyid] = C.[ipartyid]
        inner join   [dbo].D on C.[ipartyid] = D.[ipartyid]
        where        1 = 1
        and          B.[name] = @businessunit
        and          D.[lastname] = @advisor
)

select       HHName 
            ,HHID = h.ihhid
            ,FNAME = 
                case
                    when charindex(',', h.vhhname) > 0 and trim(substring(h.vhhname, patindex('% i%', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))) in ('i', 'ii', 'iii')
                    then concat(dbo.Propercase(concat(trim(substring(trim(substring(h.vhhname, charindex(' ', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))), 1, charindex(' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, charindex(' ', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname)))))), ' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, 1, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) - 1))))), UPPER(substring(h.vhhname, patindex('% i%', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))))
                    when charindex(',', h.vhhname) > 0 and nullif(h.vdescr, '') is null
                    then dbo.Propercase(replace(replace(concat(trim(substring(h.vhhname, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) + 1), len(h.vhhname))), ' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, 1, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) - 1)))), '+', '&'), ' and ', ' & '))
                    else dbo.Propercase(replace(isnull(nullif(h.vdescr, ''), h.vhhname), ' and ', ' & '))
                 end
            ,RepNo = h.planid
from         [dbo].[HH] h
inner join   
(
    select       u.[usertype]
                ,a.[user_planid]
    from         [dbo].users u
    inner join   [dbo].user_access a    on           u.iuid = a.iuid
    where        1 = 1
    and          u.[usertype] <> 'e'
    and          u.iuid =  @iuid
    group by     u.[usertype],a.[user_planid]
) p
on           h.[planid] = p.[user_planid]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you already have two SSIS variables that correspond to `@businessunit` and `@advisor` and they are being populated with the correct values already.

You can use an `Execute SQL Task` with parameter mapping to run your query. First thing you want to do is open the task editor, and configure your db connection. Next, hit the three dots next to `SQLStatement` to pull up the query editor window. Now you can start transposing your query, with a few modifications. I find that the `Execute SQL Task` works best when you separate variable declaration and assignment statements. You can use the following as your query text:

```
declare @businessunit varchar(255)
declare @advisor varchar(255)
declare @iuid int

SET @businessunit = ?
SET @advisor = ?

SET @iuid = 
(
        select       U.[iuid]
        from         U
        inner join   [dbo].A on u.[ipartyid] = A.[iuserid]
        inner join   [dbo].B on A.[ibusinessunitid] = B.[ipartyid]
        inner join   [dbo].C on u.[ipartyid] = C.[ipartyid]
        inner join   [dbo].D on C.[ipartyid] = D.[ipartyid]
        where        1 = 1
        and          B.[name] = @businessunit
        and          D.[lastname] = @advisor
)

select       HHName 
            ,HHID = h.ihhid
            ,FNAME = 
                case
                    when charindex(',', h.vhhname) > 0 and trim(substring(h.vhhname, patindex('% i%', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))) in ('i', 'ii', 'iii')
                    then concat(dbo.Propercase(concat(trim(substring(trim(substring(h.vhhname, charindex(' ', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))), 1, charindex(' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, charindex(' ', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname)))))), ' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, 1, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) - 1))))), UPPER(substring(h.vhhname, patindex('% i%', h.vhhname), len(h.vhhname))))
                    when charindex(',', h.vhhname) > 0 and nullif(h.vdescr, '') is null
                    then dbo.Propercase(replace(replace(concat(trim(substring(h.vhhname, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) + 1), len(h.vhhname))), ' ', trim(substring(h.vhhname, 1, (charindex(',', h.vhhname) - 1)))), '+', '&'), ' and ', ' & '))
                    else dbo.Propercase(replace(isnull(nullif(h.vdescr, ''), h.vhhname), ' and ', ' & '))
                 end
            ,RepNo = h.planid
from         [dbo].[HH] h
inner join   
(
    select       u.[usertype]
                ,a.[user_planid]
    from         [dbo].users u
    inner join   [dbo].user_access a    on           u.iuid = a.iuid
    where        1 = 1
    and          u.[usertype] <> 'e'
    and          u.iuid =  @iuid
    group by     u.[usertype],a.[user_planid]
) p
on           h.[planid] = p.[user_planid]
```

Hit `OK` in the query editor window. 
[image]

The `?` in the `SET` statements tell the task to pull the values from the `Parameter Mapping`. So now let's configure the parameter mappings.

In the left pane of the `Execute SQL Task Editor`, click on `Parameter Mapping`. If your db connection is OLE or EXCEL, then the `Parameter Name` will start with `0` and increment by one for each additional parameter. If it's an ODBC connection, you'll start with `1` instead. The parameter names match up with the ordinal position of the `?`. So in our example here, `@businessunit` would be the first parameter mapped and `@advisor` would be the second. Now you're going to add two parameters. Hit the `Add` button, then change the `Variable Name` to your first SSIS variable. Leave `Direction` set to `Input`, change `Data Type` to `VARCHAR`, set the `Parameter Name`, then set the `Parameter Size` to 255. Repeat for the second variable. Your paramter mappings should look something like this:

[image]

Make sure you hit `OK` to save all your changes.

Answer (score 0):

For a script as long as this, one solution that may work for you depending on what you are trying to achieve is to use [SSIS script tasks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task?view=sql-server-ver15)

Script tasks allow you to use C# (Or Visual Basic) in order to execute SQL via the same [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8) class that you would normally use in other C# programs, such as a console or ASP.NET application.

For your SQL above, put it into a stored procedure, and then execute this stored procedure within the script task. You could then use [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8) or [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8) to then read and store the result into a model.

From there, you can choose to manipulate the data within the SSIS script task.

For Example:

```cs
SqlConnection connection = new Connection("connection string");

using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Trans-SQL or stored procedure name", connection)
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(/*Add your parameters...*/);

    connection.Open()
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Use reader["name"] in here to read values from response into a model
    }
}
```

Is a completely valid way of querying data within a SSIS task. If you would rather not deal with a Reader, you can use the SqlDataAdapter and use the Fill() method to store the result(s) in a dataset.

Overall, when dealing with complex data (and where efficiency isn't too much of a concern), I find that completing actions within SSIS script tasks that get triggered by the control logic is the easier way to use SSIS.

You may find this [Integration Services Programming Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-programming-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation site useful as a reference for some of the things you can do with SSIS script tasks.

On a final note, please be aware that script tasks in SSIS do have some limitations, a key one is that there is generally worse support for newer C# features, that cause issues such as [not being able to hit debug breakpoints.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677400/vs-2015-ssis-script-tasks-cannot-be-debugged)